# email through batch script

Tags: windows, email, batch-file

This is on batch scripting again. I have tried sending email using blat and also the email.bat program given by someone in the group

using mailto , I'm getting the window open . But what i actually want is to send the mail automatically to 4 people. 
I have a batch script to check for a folder for a particular file(say .jpeg) every 2 hours and if the file appears it should send a email notification to 4 people.

[email.bat testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s80rm.jpg)

If not email, is there any other option so that a notification can be send so that the users can be informed that the jpeg file has appeared? Please help.

Comment: Okay... where is the code inside email.bat?

Answer (score 1):

This is VBScript so rename it whatever.vbs

```
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
emailObj.From     = "dc@gail.com"
emailObj.To       = "dc@gail.com"
emailObj.Subject  = "Test CDO"
emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO"

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration
msgbox emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "YourUserName"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "Password1"
emailConfig.Fields.Update

emailObj.Send

If err.number = 0 then Msgbox "Done"
```